# How to reverse colorscales in seaborn heatmap

Tags: python, plot, colors, heatmap, seaborn

For diverging values seaborn by default seems to show big numbers in warm tone (orange) and small numbers in cold tone (blue).

If I need to switch color to opposite, to show big numbers in blue and small in orange, how to do so?

I've searched but haven't found a way.

```
sns.heatmap(flights, center=flights.loc["January", 1955])
```

Comment: Find the max value of your data and subtract each element from the max value to get the inverted values and plot similarly

Comment: Post a reproducible example. I took a stab at what you've done below. But it's just a guess since I can't read your mind.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can reverse all of the matplotlib colormaps by appending `_r` to the name, i.e., `plt.cm.coolwarm` vs `plt.cm.coolwarm_r`.

I believe seaborn uses a cubehelix colormap by default.

So you'd do:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import seaborn as sns

colormap = pyplot.cm.cubehelix_r
flights = sns.load_dataset('flights').pivot("month", "year", "passengers")
sns.heatmap(flights, cmap=colormap)
```

Comment: You don't need to pass the colormap object; a string will work too.

Comment: Great! Thanks. Nice hint. `cmap="magma_r` i.e. worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to build a separate reverse function for heatmap.

Just use **cmap = 'magma_r'**. The default setting is magma and thus we just append the '_r' for reverse.